How Can I Optimize My Recursive Fibonacci Function to Improve Performance?
I created a recursive function to calculate Fibonacci numbers, but it's extremely slow for large values of n. I know that the inefficiency comes from recalculating the same Fibonacci values multiple times. How can I improve this algorithm's performance?
I used a basic recursive approach
function fibonacci(n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    }
}

While this method works, it has a high time complexity due to redundant calculations. What can I do to optimize it for larger values of n?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can just store the value in an array and reuse the (two last) computed values rather than recomputing them recursively every time. This changes the complexity to O(2**n) to O(n). This is a very very famous optimization. You should do some research before asking this here. Note there is an even faster algorithm based on matrix which is described on Wikipedia (one of the first website to check before posting here too). People will likely downvote the question due to the lack of the search effort.

The many answers given in the closure link are all O(2**n) time or O(n) time. The most efficient algorithm exact algorithm (rather than an approximation or estimate) is actually O(log n) time. It casts the basic recurrence as multiplication of a starting value by a 2x2 matrix M. Calculating fibonacci(n) is then M**n times the starting point. This sounds worse, but powers can be calculated in O(log n) by successive squaring of the matrix and halving the exponent. The complexity isn't worth it for small values of n, but is great if you start getting into BigInteger ranges.

See the third case in this answer for an implementation.

For real world applications with limited value-types you can precalculate all Fibonacci Numbers and store them in an array. For 32 Bit variables only 47th Fibonacci numbers are possible for 64 bit variables  93 Fibonacci numbers.

Allocate an array with stored values.
Fibonacci (n) returns the stored value if possible, otherwise does a recursive call and stores the value. This runs in constant time because every value will be calculated only once.

"This runs in constant time." No, it runs in linear time - and uses linear memory. It's easy to write an iterative approach that works up from 0 instead of down from n though - that's linear in time and constant in memory.

The problem your having is typical of the naive recursion of the Fibonacci sequence. They all have the exponential time complexity, which is clearly seen given the function factored as it is, O(2^n), due to the fact that each function recalculates the Fibonacci numbers.
Optimized Approaches

Memoization (Top-Down Dynamic Programming):
To improve the recursive function, one of the best ways is the optimization technique called memoization. This is a caching technique where the Fibonacci results that have been earlier computed are not required to be computed again.

Here’s how you can implement it:Here’s how you can implement it:
Here the implementing of a recursive function type is defined.
if n is less than or equal to one {
return n;
}
if (memo[n]) {
return memo[n];
}
memo[n] = fibonacci(n-1, memo) + fibonacci(n-2,memo)
return memo[n];
}
Explanation:

To this end, we create a memo object (or an array) where the computed Fibonacci numbers are to be stored.
In particular, before calculating fibonacci(n), the function checks whether n is already existing in memo. If it is, the function pass the result as is to the next step or returns it.
If it does not, the function calculates it, then store the result in memo before display the value.
This helps reduce the time complexity down to n hence faster when n is large in the second for loop.

2. Iterative Approach (Bottom-Up Dynamic Programming):Iterative Approach (Bottom-Up Dynamic Programming):
A different approach can be taken and it does not involve recursion and is iterative in nature. This is sometimes even faster because some languages are not very optimized with recursion methodology.




 function fibonacci(n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
    return n;
    }
    let prev = 0, curr = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i ≤ n; i++) {
    let temp = curr;
    curr = curr + prev;
    prev = temp;
    }
    return curr;
    }

